# Subsequent Calls to RequestStatusesWithDocumentFields Return Zero Results

Tags: docusignapi

We are using the DocuSign SOAP API 3.0 and have the following method in our application:

```
public EnvelopeStatus[] GetDocuSignEnvelopes(DateTime beginDateTime)
    {
        var envelopeStatusFilter = new EnvelopeStatusFilter
        {
            AccountId = _client.DocuSignAccountId,
            BeginDateTime = new EnvelopeStatusFilterBeginDateTime { Value = beginDateTime },
            Statuses = new[] { EnvelopeStatusCode.Completed }
        };
        var envelopeStatuses = _docuSignApi.RequestStatusesWithDocumentFields(envelopeStatusFilter);
        return envelopeStatuses.EnvelopeStatuses.OrderBy(x => x.Completed).ToArray();
    }
```

In performing a test by creating and completing an envelope, this code works as it should and returns back an EnvelopeStatus array containing the one envelope.  However, if we immediately call this method again, that same envelope is not returned.  In fact, the array is empty.  And, yes, we have ensured that the beginDateTime is set to a value prior to when the envelope was created for each iteration.

Therefore, my question is this... **Does the DocuSign SOAP API somehow keep track of what envelopes were retrieved previously via the API and then exclude them from the result set?**  If not, then why would subsequent calls with the same parameter values not return the same results?

If this method does exclude results, that's fine, but I need to know the parameters of this exclusion in order to properly deal with them in our code.  For example, does it exclude based on the specific integrator key, a certain amount of calls in a specific time range, etc.?  Basically, in what scenarios will the excluded results ever be added back in to the result set?

As a follow on, if we have an issue processing an envelope once received and we do need to get a "fresh list" of envelopes from the DocuSign API (even though they might have been retrieved in the past), how would we go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I've never personally used this SOAP operation, but I know that DocuSign does impose some restrictions when it comes to polling for Envelope status, in terms of how frequently you're allowed poll for status. The DocuSign API Best Practices guide contains details about these restrictions:  http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/SOAP_REST_API_Best_Practices_with_Connect_Guide.pdf

If possible, best practice would be to use DocuSign Connect (http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/DocuSign_Connect_Service_Guide.pdf) to automatically receive event notifications re Envelope status changes, instead of polling for status using API requests.